# how to implement a third party plugin e.g IAP, Ad Network, Social Sharing with ECS/DOD.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, data-driven, data-oriented-design

I have started looking into ECS recently for game development. Til now I used and fancied OOP and patterns for code separation, ECS also does so but in another way.
I'm getting my head over designing data in ECS. I seems logical for game related stuff.. like Position component Rotation Component Price Component etc in some base building game or any other. but we also have to integrate plugins IAP, Analytics, Social Features, Ad Networks and I'm currently unable to understand how to construct these with ECS only OOP comes in my mind.
E.g

- there can be multiple social features. share on FB, Twitter.
- Implement different or same adNetowrks for different platforms.

These features can use different plugins/SDKs/Classes for different platforms(IOS, Android, Windows etc).

Im using Unity Game Engine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coroutine wrong Behavior when scene is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276811/coroutine-wrong-behavior-when-scene-is-loaded)