# Coroutine wrong Behavior when scene is loaded

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok so I have this coroutine :

```
 IEnumerator ShowCharTraits()
    {

        while(!hasPlayerChosen)
        {
            yield return null;
            traitPanel.SetActive(true);
        }
        hasPlayerChosen = false;
        traitPanel.SetActive(false);
    //    Debug.Log("Got called! job done");

    }
```

It's being called like this from the awake method in my `GameManager`:

```
players = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
                foreach (GameObject g in players)
                {
                    ui_Controller.StartShowCharTraits();
                    g.GetComponent<PlayerToken>().isTurn = false;
                }
```

StartShowCharTraits() is a simple method that does this :

```
  public void StartShowCharTraits()
    {
        StartCoroutine("ShowCharTraits");
    }
```

Now, I have checked the tags, no null reference exception, actually no errors or warnings are being thrown. If i load the scene in the editor and then play it everything works fine. `traitPanel.SetActive(true);` get called and my panel shows up. However when I load my scene from another scene using   `SceneManager.LoadScene(1);` the above mentioned line is never reached. Any ideas why this is happening ?

Comment: can you tell which specific line is not being called? can you atleast do a debug.log to check if the coroutines working

Comment: I do tell which specific line is not being called. And I already answered my own question. The problem was lets say in a different place.

Comment: i have put in an exciting answer for you @uripopov !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you want to have one central place that is "like a singleton" in a Unity project.  Example,

```
SoundEffects
LapTimer
Scores
SocialMediaConnections
```

All you do is this.

1. make your script SoundEffects.cs
2. recall that **every** Unity project **must have** a "preload" scene. (it's impossible to not have one)
3. in the preload scene, have a empty game object called "holder".  make sure it is marked "DontDestroyOnLoad"
4. attach SoundEffects.cs to that holder

you're done.

there's just nothing more to it.

you're finished.

it's "just that simple"

So, any particular script, which happens to be attached to any particular object, in any particular scene, may need to access "SoundEffects"...

To do so, simply do this in Awake:

```
 SoundEffects soundEffects = Object.FindObjectOfType<SoundEffects>();
```

then just use `soundEffects` anywhere in that script, for example `soundEffects.PlayBoom(13)` etc etc.

So in Awake()

```
  Laps laps = Object.FindObjectOfType<Laps>();
  Social social = Object.FindObjectOfType<Social>();
  AI ai = Object.FindObjectOfType<AI>();
```

or whatever.

Unity is simple. *Incredibly simple.*  It's just that easy.

1. write your script, `LapTimer.cs` or whatever
2. put it on a holder object in your preload scene (where else could it be?)

there's no "3", that's all there is.  It's just that ridiculously simple.

## Note that...

> In the early days of Unity, someone unfortunately mentioned "singletons" on a QA board somewhere.  (You can't have "singletons" in an ECS system, it's meaningless.) At the time, this led to huge discussions about how you can make a "singleton-like thingy" in Unity, which is piling confusion on confusion. Unfortunately from that day to this, you get people learning Unity, who see "singleton" mentioned here and there on the net, and it leads to endless confusion.

**Once again, note that the idea of "managers" is just impossibly simple in Unity - explained above. It's trivial. It just couldn't be easier.**

---

Note, above I mention you might want **syntactic candy** to avoid the incredible chore of typing `Laps laps = Object.FindObjectOfType<Laps>();`

There are very unfortunately **no macros** in Unity/c# so you need another way.

All you do is use a **"Grid"** script http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1124859/view.html which has been popular for years in Unity.

But honestly, it's so simple to use `Scores scores = Object.FindObjectOfType<Scores>();` that I usually just do that nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for the greaet answer as always. I'm already doing this. I have a object that is DontDestroyOnLoad() in my first scene. The problem came from the fact that the Dataholder attached to it looks if there are any other instance of it and destroys them when it enters the scene. This caused another object holding specific scene scripts to be destroyed because sadly it had a DataHolder instance attached to it from testing.So what happened was that the Awake() of one script was calling the coroutine for the chars and while that was running the awake from DataHodler was deleting the whole object

Comment: My main menu scene does this. The problem was I had forgotten a DataHolder component on a game object in another scene. That game object was being destroyed from the DataHolder coming from the main menu scene. The same gameobject help scripts for the scene. That's why everything broke.

Comment: Going back and forth from the main menu is not the problem here. I already solved my problem by changing the Awake() of the DataHolder I dont know how to explain what happened any better than I already have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112278/discussion-between-uri-popov-and-joe-blow).

Answer (score -1):

Ok how do I explain this. I have a singleton that acts as a data holder. While developing the scene with the game manager I had attached the singleton to the gamemanger object that hold a bunch of scripts. Now when I made the main menu I ofc added my singleton to it so I can carry info to the game scene and because of this my whole game manger object was being deleted. This is the culprit from the DataHolder :

```
 void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        else if (instance != this)
            Destroy(gameObject);//This right here.

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
```

So I changed that line to             `Destroy(gameObject.GetComponent(instance.GetType()));`

Comment: singleton?  there are no singletons in Unity dude.  you can't really have them.

Comment: In C# you can? I use one in my MusicController. http://ghettocode.blogspot.com/2016/04/creating-musiccontroller-module-in.html

Comment: @JoeBlow wait doesnt the fact that my script guarantees that there is only one instance of the DataHolder object make it a singleton ?

Comment: in Unity it's absolutely impossible to guarantee that there will only be one of a given component in a scene.  it's utterly meaningless to try to make "something like a singleton" in an ECS system like Unity.  it would be like saying you want the pixels in a photoshop scene or the letters in a text editor scene to be ...  "singletons".  it's meaningless.